# PHP7 Constructor class name

Tags: php, laravel-4, constructor

I have a Laravel 4.2 application which works with PHP5 without any problems. Since I installed a new vagrant box running PHP7 an error appears as soon as I run a model where the name of a function is the same as the class name (relationship-function) like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Participant extends \Eloquent
{

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    [...]

    public function participant()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    [...]    

}
```

I get the following error message:

> Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Participant has a deprecated constructor (View: ...)

So what I didn't know until today is, that in PHP4 methods with the same name were the contructor of a class. Hmm. I am really a bad programmer... But in this case, from my understanding of what is happening in PHP7, they correct a failure of mine as I never wanted to use this function as a constructor, since it defines only an Eloquent relationship.

But how can I get rid of this message? As I understand this, in PHP4 my code was buggy, but not in PHP7, right? If not necessary I do not want to refactor this function, as it is used in several places.

Can anybody explain what I am doing wrong and why it worked with older PHP versions?

Thanks!

Comment: "Hmm. I am really a bad programmer..."
:-D

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> As I understand this, in PHP4 my code was buggy, but not in PHP7, right?

Not quite. *PHP4-style constructors still work on PHP7*, they are just been deprecated and they will trigger a Deprecated warning.

What you can do is define a `__construct` method, even an empty one, so that the php4-constructor method won't be called on a newly-created instance of the class.

```
class foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Constructor's functionality here, if you have any.
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        // PHP4-style constructor.
        // This will NOT be invoked, unless a sub-class that extends `foo` calls it.
        // In that case, call the new-style constructor to keep compatibility.
        self::__construct();
    }
}

new foo();
```

It worked with older PHP versions simply because constructors don't get return value. Every time you created a Participant instance, you implicitly call the `participant` method, that's all.

Comment: That was easy! Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed!

Comment: Hi! thats a partial solution. Take a look at https://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php4-constructors-php7.htm . If the old constructor is called explicitly from a subclass then it will fail. To completely solve it you must move the constructor's functionality to the new-style constructor (__construct) and call it (self::__construct();) from the old-style constructor. Best regards, /Ángel

Comment: Thanks to point out that @Angel. You can edit my answer and add this if you want.

Comment: question about this - why `self::__construct()` instead of `$this->__construct()`?  Would there be any difference in one or the other in this context?

Comment: Yeah @billynoah, if you use `$this->__construct()` you could have problems with any potential sub-class. [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/AeZDLq0Y) is recursive,  [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/5UzsGEFH) isn't.

Answer (score 7):

PHP 4 style constructors (methods that have the same name as the class they are defined in) are deprecated, and will be removed in the future. PHP 7 will emit E_DEPRECATED if a PHP 4 constructor is the only constructor defined within a class. Classes that implement a __construct() method are unaffected.

```
<?php
    class foo {
        function foo() {
            echo 'I am the constructor';
         }
     }
?>
```

You can keep your old constructor but you need to add a new construct like that:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingTrait;

class Participant extends \Eloquent
{

    use SoftDeletingTrait;

    [...]

    public function __construct()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function participant()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    [...]    

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I needed. Only the contructor should be empty in my case, as statet by @Federico.

Comment: A constructor, such as __construct(), may never contain a return statement, though.