# Laravel 5.6 - Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP

Tags: php, deprecated, laravel-5.6, nusoap, php-7.2

I am using Laravel 5.6 framework running under PHP 7.2.3 version.I have an error while i'm trying to use [econea nusoap](https://github.com/econea/nusoap) library and i've got the following error: **Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; nusoap_client has a deprecated constructor**

What can i do to solve this issue? I think is cause of PHP version.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What version of this package do you use?

Comment: @thefallen I use 0.9.6

Comment: You may found your answer in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616448/php7-nusoap-nusoap-client-has-a-deprecated-constructor

Comment: @GuillaumeCozic Thank you mate, already tried but doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constructor. More complete [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36339774/php7-constructor-class-name).

```
class foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    // Constructor's functionality here, if you have any.
    }

    public function foo()
    {
    // PHP4-style constructor.
    // This will NOT be invoked, unless a sub-class that extends `foo` calls it.
    // In that case, call the new-style constructor to keep compatibility.
    self::__construct();
   }
}
```